# RailsAdmin + Nested Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin

I have Company that has many Phones.

I created seed data to add 1 company and 1 phone

When RailsAdmin renders the company form, the nested fields for phone show correctly.

When I click "Add new phone", it adds 2 tabs (each says "Phone (new)") but can't get the fields to display.  I click "Add new phone" again and again get 2 more tabs but no way to enter data.

```
def Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones
  attr_accessible :name, :phones_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |obj| obj.blank? }
end

def Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, :inverse => :phones
  attr_accessible :number, :provider, :phone_type
end
```

BTW - doesn't matter if edit or new, both "Add new phone" does not show any fields to enter data.

Comment: what says the console? and what's in development.log file?

Comment: when I click "Add new" tabs show, but nothing shows in log as if web request was never made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had this same problem going from rails 3.1.3 to 3.2.6. I solved it by adding the id's and foreign_id's to attr_accessible.

```
def Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones
  attr_accessible :id, :name, :phones_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |obj| obj.blank? }
end

def Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, :inverse => :phones
  attr_accessible :id, :number, :provider, :phone_type, :company_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps much but I had this problem too because I was using another nested form gem that conflicted (at least in JS) with the one RailsAdmin depends on. When I removed that gem (awesome_nested_forms I believe), all the built in RailsAdmin has_many association widgets functioned properly again.